# Copy values of a worksheet to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do something that seems simple, but keeps on causing me trouble.

Copying the active worksheet into a new workbook without formulas.

I've tried my luck with the following code:

```
Sub test()
ActiveSheet.Copy
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

But that is quite unreliable, as it sometimes doesn't copy fields that clearly has a value.
I have cells that needs to have text that is both bold and normal and different sizes in the same damn cell.

The aforementioned method does not keep that formatting.

What I am currently doing looks like this:

```
Sub EksporterExcel()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim tid As String

Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
tid = Format(CStr(Now), "hh.mm.ss")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws.Copy
Set wb = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
ws.UsedRange.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        FileFormat:=51, _
        Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Udfyldte Indleveringsplaner\Excel\" & Date & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " Kl. " & tid & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And that works.

It is however slow. Very, very slow. I'm assuming that this has to do with copying the sheet first and the going back to copy the cell values, so I'd like a way to avoid that.

This way also doesn't keep the formatting in the single cells that has multiple formatting options. That's low priority however.

I would love to know if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Below is an example of the result when using the first snippet of code, or the code in the answer by jkpieterse.

[image: The original sheet]
The original sheet before being copied.

[image: The copied sheet]
The copied sheet

Some of the data is clearly lost after being copied

Comment: What do you mean by "without formulas"? Paste to destination as values? Paste empty values into destination where there's a formula in the source?

Comment: I need the value that the user sees when looking at the sheet. Apparently that is not the same as .Value in all cases, seeing as the first piece of code is unreliable

Comment: the reason it is soooo slow is youre traversing the entire workbook/worksheet.

Comment: Can I avoid that by simple stating the range that I need to be copied then? The worksheet has a fixed size

Comment: Using `ws.UsedRange.Copy` is a bit faster, but not much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this version (also tidied up some of your code):

```
Sub EksporterExcel()
    Dim tid As String

    tid = Format(CStr(Now), "hh.mm.ss")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Copy

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            FileFormat:=51, _
            Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Udfyldte Indleveringsplaner\Excel\" & Date & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " Kl. " & tid & ".xlsx"
    'Assume it is the active workbook you wanted to close...
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Same problem here as with the small snippet of code up there. For some reason, not all values are actually copied, and the copied values don't seem to have a pattern. I'll upload two pictures in the original post to illustrate the problem

Comment: Sounds to as if your original sheet is somehow (partly) corrupted. Does the sheet contain any merged cells? If so, what happens if you unmerge those first?

Comment: There's way too many merged cells for my own good, but I can't do much about them. That's not really up to me you see. I tried unmerging them though for the sake of the experiment, and the problem did persist even then

Comment: I think you can safely assume the sheet is corrupt. Best thing to do is insert a new worksheet and copy paste everything from the old to the new. Then try the copy worksheet trick to see if the new sheet does copy as expected. If it fails again, you will have to recreate the worksheet by copying and pasting just formulas. Take it one step at the time, retrying the worksheet copy at each intermediate step.

Comment: Oh boy... That's a lot of copying. There's 15 sheets in the workbook. Well, I kind of wanted to do that anyway, as there's two phantom sheets in VBA for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out. The cells whose value disappears all refer to named ranges, and in the formula for those I've added an IFERROR = "". I removed that and now the cells in the copied sheet all return #Reference rather than a blank space. Why on earth isn't the reference broken though? I do not want named ranged nor references in the copied sheet, just values

Comment: The problem was solved by adding `Dim Original As Worksheet` `Set Original = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = Original.UsedRange.Value2` in order to gather the values from the original worksheet, rather than the copied one, which gets around the broken references

Comment: This is precisely why the IFERROR function is such a dangerous one, it hides structural errors too.

Comment: Indeed. I'll try to work my way out of having to use that one